# How to create an App Events object without using ThisWorkbook?

Tags: excel, vba

Inherited a rather large selection of spreadsheets for multiple clients.

Some of these have multiple ThisWorkbooks (e.g. ThisWorkbook, ThisWorkbook2, etc...).

Trying to put some event code check to automatically run when the workbook is opened. Either Workbook or App Events could be a solution.

The recommendation from http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx suggests adding something like the following code to ThisWorkbook.

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

The issue is that if there are multiple ThisWorkbooks, the code never runs.

Actually, testing shows if I put it into ThisWorkbook1, it runs from there. LOL.

Main Question: Is there an event to create an Application Events object that doesn't use ThisWorkbook when opening a spreadsheet?

Basically another "code gate" that is always guaranteed to run that doesn't require ThisWorkbook.

I suspect "No", but any confirmation or alternative would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: "It there are multiple ThisWorkbooks" ...`ThisWorkbook` represents the host document, the `Workbook` that contains your VBA project - there can never be "multiple ThisWorkbooks".

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to avoid code in `ThisWorkbook`, or what makes you think any handler other than the `Open` event is guaranteed to run: once a workbook is opened, the next thing to happen might very well be that the same workbook gets closed, and then no other event fires the that workbook. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: >>there can never be "multiple ThisWorkbooks. Unfortumately, I am getting muliple ThisWorkbooks like this https://superuser.com/questions/1048265/remove-multiple-thisworkbook-modules-from-excel-vba-editor.

Comment: Your file is most likely corrupted then (as I stated in the answer to that post); this isn't normal. I would rebuild the entire file from scratch - export all modules, reimport them into a brand new project/workbook, and recreate the sheets (don't move them to the new project). You can only expect increasingly unstable/weird behavior from a corrupted workbook.

Comment: >>I don't understand why you're trying to avoid code in `ThisWorkbook`. I'm avoiding `ThisWorkbook` because if there are > 1, the events in `ThisWorkbook` never get attached if opening a corrupted workbook.

Comment: See if `Auto_Open` works then. But I'd warmly recommend fixing/rebuilding the broken file instead. You don't know what the next thing to break will be. I wouldn't be surprised if Excel promptly just crashed upon opening it - better recreate it in a sane host document before it's too late.

Comment: Yes, the file is corrupted from the start. I needed a way to let the user know it's corrupt. Putting together a procedure for users based on http://excelexperts.com/Excel-Tips-Fix-Corrupt-Spreadsheet. `Public Sub Auto_Open()` seems exactly what I was looking for. Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Workbook.Open` event is the modern way to get code to run on open.

The legacy way is to have a specially named macro in a standard module:

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
    MsgBox "Works!"
End Sub
```

That *should* pop the message box on open.

As mentioned in the comments, a sane Excel file only has a single `Workbook` module - there being more than one means the file is corrupted in some way, and that can't be good. I'd recommend rebuilding the broken files: you never know when a corrupted file will just outright crash Excel for no apparent reason.

Comment: This allows Excel to tell the user if they've opened a corrupt workbook. Also to create event hooks for OnBeforeSave to double check before saving a workbook with corruption or bad references. This will help catch errors as soon as possible. Cheers to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why the corruption is happening, but it's happening enough across various spreadsheets to be worrisome.

Created code to test for a bad `ThisWorkbook` upon opening and not allow saving if `ThisWorkbook` is bad.

1 regular module (`modAutoOpenAndClose`) and 1 class module (`classWBEvents`).

Putting these 2 modules into all spreadsheets as standard procedure. As mentioned above in the comments, users will then follow the instructions from [Excel Experts Tips to Fix Corrupt Spreadsheet](http://excelexperts.com/Excel-Tips-Fix-Corrupt-Spreadsheet).

Hopefully these are useful to anyone else experiencing/preventing corruption. May seem like overkill, but this has been a bedeviling issue.

```
Option Explicit

'modAutoOpenAndClose

Dim WorkbookEvents As classWBEvents

Function ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad() As Boolean
  On Error GoTo ErrLabel
  ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad = Not (ThisWorkbook.CodeName = "ThisWorkbook")
  Exit Function
ErrLabel:
  ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad = True
End Function

Private Sub Auto_Open()
  If ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad Then
    Call MsgBox("This Spreadsheet is Corrupt." + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + _
                 "Please Copy Tabs And Modules to New Spreadsheet." + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + _
                 "Saving will not be allowed.", vbCritical)
  End If

  Set WorkbookEvents = New classWBEvents
  Set WorkbookEvents.WB = ActiveWorkbook
  If Not WorkbookEvents.WB Is Nothing Then
    WorkbookEvents.WB_Open
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Auto_Close()
  If Not WorkbookEvents Is Nothing Then
    If Not WorkbookEvents.WB Is Nothing Then
      Set WorkbookEvents.WB = Nothing
    End If
    Set WorkbookEvents = Nothing
  End If
End Sub
```

And

```
Option Explicit

'classWBEvents

Public WithEvents WB As Workbook
Private Sub WB_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  If ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad Then
    Call MsgBox("This Spreadsheet is Corrupt." + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + _
                "Please Copy Tabs And Modules to New Spreadsheet." + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + _
                "Saving will not be allowed.", vbCritical)

    Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub WB_Open()
  'Reserved for project specific code
End Sub
```

Comment: I traced this down to a call to `Application.Volatile` causing the corruption. Don't know why that would be, but the corruption happens when `Application.Volatile` is there and doesn't when it's not.